# How to make portable exe program (C#) use a database (SQL Server Express) on a local network

Tags: c#, sql, exe

I'm designing a portable c# program with a SQL Server Express database (`.mdf` file) which will be used by multiple computers. And I'm trying to make every user work on the same database allocated on a certain computer on the local network.

My problem is when a convert my C# program portable exe, I can't make my program to use the specified database on network. It only sees the database I attached on the folder which contains my portable exe program.

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Gorev.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

This is my connection string. Did I make a mistake?

I use Visual C# 2010 Express edition as compiler.

Please help me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have SQL server installed somewhere on the network, if so what is the name of that computer? That name needs to go in the connection string.

Comment: Your connection string refers to a local database instance. You need to make sure your database is accessible on the network, and change your connection string to access it over the network.

Comment: There could be many reasons...Firewall, missing server name, permissions, etc. See this as it may help:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Comment: Can you show us the error when the program is trying to access the database?

Answer (score 3):

I think you connection string is wrong
You should first Attach your database on server Computer that hosted your SQLServer 
Then on connection string change`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS`to`Data Source=ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS` and then Instated off`AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Gorev.mdf`you should Set Database name like this`Initial catalog=Gorev`

finally you connection string should be like follow line

```
connectionString="Data Source=ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog=Gorev;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

ComputerName should be name of computers is hosted SQLServer
SQLEXPRESS is Instance of SQLServer and this name is Default and you should replace with you sqlserver instance 

Pleas Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx How to enable SqlSever for remote connection

Pleas Visit
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
sql server Connection string Pattern